# Flex Builder: not picking up index.template.html

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm using Flex Builder 3 and in my html-template directory I have my index.template.html. However, Flex Builder is not generating the proper binary .html file for me. What could be wrong? I've diffed the index.template.html to someone's else (whose works). Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Flex Builder isn't generating the binary files? ( AKA SWFs? ) or Flex Builder isn't generating the HTML Files associated with the swfs?

Most of the issues I've seen with generated HTML have been related to the html-template directory being emtpy, not the files not being generated.

Do you have Build Automatically turned on?  Have you tried to clean the project?  Have you tried to change the SDK version [then change it back].